# how to find unmatched record from two row in one table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table **student**.

```
**id | name | age | email | address**
------------------------------
 1   | abc  | 20  | abc@gmail.com  |  street number10
------------------------------
 2   | def  | 25  | def@gmail.com  |  street number12
------------------------------
 3   |hjk  | 20  | hjk@gmail.com  |  street number10
------------------------------
 4   | umnnn  | 20  | umnn@gmail.com  |  street number10
```

I want to match rows and want unmatched record.

*EXAMPLE:*

> row 3rd(id=3) should be matched with row 4th (id=4) and should give
>   only unmatched value of 4th row means value of id=4, name=umnn,
>   email=umnn@gmail.com only, not should be age and address.
>
> row 2nd(id=2) should be matched with row 3rd (id=3) and should give
>   only unmatched value of 3rd row means value of id=3, name=hkj, age=20,
>   email=hkj@gmail.com, address=street number10.

and like this 1st and 2nd row should be matched and should be give value of 2nd row id,name,age,email only.

Comment: I have no any idea that how to solve it. Please give me any code. its very urgent.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    s2.id,
    IF (s1.name = s2.name, NULL, s2.name) as name,
    IF (s1.age = s2.age, NULL, s2.age) as age,
    IF (s1.email = s2.email, NULL, s2.email) as email,
    IF (s1.address = s2.address, NULL, s2.address) as address
FROM student s1
LEFT JOIN student s2 ON s1.id < s2.id
GROUP BY s1.id
ORDER BY s1.id, s2.id
```